# How does Polymorph Any Object work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

## *Transmutation Is Weird #1*

[*Polymorph any object*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph-any-object) can turn an object or creature into another creature or object, for a duration from 20 minutes to Permanent. The FAQ *recommends* that [*Polymorph*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph) and such not copy advanced forms of creatures, because (paraphrased) 'it'd be a headache.'

I'm dissatisfied with the FAQ's suggestion that *polymorph* shouldn't be allowed to produce Advanced versions of creatures, and that any humanoids formed from objects should be 1HD commoners.

- Can *polymorph*, *polymorph any object*, or [*shapechange*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shapechange) actually copy advanced forms of creatures, including humanoids?
- If yes regarding objects becoming advanced humanoids, how would you adjudicate that advancement?

Comment: If you answer your own question, you should post it as an answer, but if your research changes the question without answering it, you should edit the question. So the answer is, "it depends!"

Comment: I think this is a series of different questions: 1) *Ignoring the FAQ, does* polymorph any object *as written allow the creation of advanced creature or creatures with classes?* is a fine question, but getting folks to disregard a resource is difficult; 2) *When a creature created from nonliving material by* polymorph any object *dies and reverts to its original material, can it be returned from the dead?* is a good question; 3) *Can a creature created by* polymorph any object *advance?* is reasonable, but unlikely to have a definitive answer; and…

Comment: …4) *Can a corpse created by* flesh to stone *be the subject of an* animate *or* raise dead *spell?* is a fantastic question. Consider chopping this question down to just #1 instead. I can edit this to do that if you want. (You might be sick of looking at this question by now.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I'll pare it to Your #1, Then I'll ask 2 and 4 later.

Comment: So, um, how should polymorphing into a minotaur fighter 4 work?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

To the best of my knowledge, there is no rule explicitly preventing usage of *polymorph* or *polymorph any object* to assume the form of an advanced creature.

The usual advancement rules apply (see *Monster Manual* section on advancing monsters).

While I can't point out a rule disallowing that, I'd say no to advancement by character class.

That said, I don't think advanced creature forms are the worst issue with *polymorph* spells; you'd better watch out for *metamorphic transfer* and *assume supernatural ability*.

Comment: Quite true, regarding MMXfer and ASA, but the first is uses/day, and the second requires a DC 19 Will save in 'stressful situations' or it fails. The save can be obviated alternate rounds by the *Moment of Perfect Mind* Diamond Mind counter, but I've not found a lot else.

Comment: @Chemus  I'd rather not consider DC 19 Will save an issue at all, and uses/day issue is usually circumvented with duration of each use (*wild shape*, *PAO*). Furthermore, finding oneself in a situation sticky enough to warrant a nasty combat form multiple times daily is a planning issue.